# How To Prevent PHP Form Submission Through AJAX?

Tags: php, html, ajax

I want to prevent the main form to be submitted according to AJAX response.

HTML is like this...

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="email" id="email" onblur="ajax_check_email();">
   <span id="email_alert"></span>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Now I have a js file with ajax query -

```
function ajax_email_check () {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("email_alert").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax/check_email.php?email=" + email,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Now the php page returns `Email Already Exists` or `Success`.

All goes well but after showing the Text that the "email already exists...!" the main form is getting submitted when I hit submit. It should prevent me. But how am I gonna do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a flag like `var shouldSubmit = false`, in your ajax response, if it's okay to submit, change `shouldSubmit` to `true`, then add a eventlistener to form

```
<script>
    yourform.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
    if(!shouldSubmit){
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
       }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just catch the event and stop it.

```
<form id="myform" action="test.php" method="POST">
<script>
$('form#myform').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in **form tag** `onsubmit="return false;"`

Like this-

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return false;">
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" onblur="ajax_check_email();">
<span id="email_alert"></span>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: That will prevent the form to get submitted permanently... I was asking that how to make the form submit-able when ajax response text is "Success...!".